# std::pair - error: wrong number of template argument

Tags: c++, std-pair

I have a std::pair declaration shown in below code snippet and g++ issues below compilation error at line 152 saying "error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)". I am new to this std::pair thing and I wonder what I am doing wrong. So mentioned line number has been marked in the code snippet below. Thanks.

```
  std::vector< 
              std::pair<EndPointAddr* requesterServiceAddr, 
                        EndPointAddr*  requestedServiceAddr>* //LINE 152 is HERE
             > mServiceSubscriptionsList; 


  In file included from ServiceRegistrar.hpp:8:0,
                   from ServiceRegistrar.cpp:7:
  ../control_api/ServiceRegistrarAPI.hpp:152:95: error: wrong number of template   arguments (1, should be 2)
  ........
  .......
  ../control_api/ServiceRegistrarAPI.hpp:153:14: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  ../control_api/ServiceRegistrarAPI.hpp:153:14: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  In file included from ../control_api/ServiceRegistrarAPI.cpp:5:0:
```

Comment: "`EndPointAddr* requesterServiceAddr`" - don't give it a name, `std::pair` only wants types. Also, too many doggamn pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::pair`  Only needs the **types** in a declaration.

```
std::vector< 
          std::pair<EndPointAddr*, 
                    EndPointAddr* >* //LINE 152 is HERE
         > mServiceSubscriptionsList;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a type as a template argument, not a variable:

```
std::vector< std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr*>* >
```